# How to directly access env var in Windows right after setting this var

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

When in run

```
SET TEST_VAR=my_var && echo %TEST_VAR%
```

I get:

```
%TEST_VAR%
```

Which mean I cannot access the setted env var in the current process.

How can I get the `TEST_VAR` var in the same process ?

I need it in the same process because I'm running this code in dart like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) {
  Process.run(r"SET TEST_VAR=my_var && echo %TEST_VAR%", [], runInShell: true);
}
```

Ps: it's not the real command but I'm running a third party code which require some env var to be setted.

Comment: If you do `set var=value && program` or simply `set var=value & program` where program is really a program not a CMD builtin like `echo` the program _will_ get the envvar setting, but using it in CMD itself on one line including in /C (or /K) won't. I don't know (anything) about DART, but in Java feeding those commands as (two) different lines of _input_ to CMD (and not commandline) works.